# trending topics "bubble chart" with time slider and bubbles atracted to each other

Tags: bubble-chart

Back in 2013, in Brazil, someone created this visualization for trending topics. It is no longer available. But, as the images below show, it featured:

- a horizontal slider to select the time: t.
- topics represented by bubbles, whose size was proportional to how many citations it had in that interval.
- bubbles would attract each other, but not overlap
- as you moved the slider bubbles would "move", with the largest moving to the center
- as you click in a bubble, a text box would open, with details about that topic.

I am trying to recreate something similar. Any ideas on which technologies (programming language, library) could I use to implement that?

[image]

[image]